# How to easily calculate the size and position of text that is crooked without rotation?

Tags: geometry, angle

I have created this picture for illustration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TQJt.png)

I want to use it in a program, but this is a math problem, so I'm writing it here.

When I know the dimensions, I can calculate the height of the letters if all the spaces are 5.

**textHeight = (height - ((numberOfLetters + 2) * 5)) / numberOfLetters**

**In the picture: textHeight = (800 - 10 * 5) / 9**

Although the letters have a height higher than the width, the shape does not have to be square, so it is not possible to predict whether the width will exceed the maximum width. If so, I would still have to calculate the width.

**textWidth = (width - ((numberOfLetters + 2) * 5)) / numberOfLetters**

**In the picture: textWidth = (800 - 10 * 5) / 9** (actually using monospaced text so it's possible)

However, the size of the letter is not defined by the width, and that is the problem. Is it possible to calculate the height so that it does not exceed the maximum width? In addition, if I know the ratio between width and height.

The second problem is positioning. It can be calculated using a diagonal, but by starting with the middle letter in the middle of the square. But it would be easier to start from the first letter. In addition, if the word does not have an odd number of letters, there will be nothing in the middle.

PS. The spaces between the edge of the square and the first and last letter may of course be larger, but there will always be 5 between the individual letters.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: *"How do I calculate whether to pay attention"* - the word "whether" is usually used for classification problems, not calculation. The question is quite unclear to me.

Comment: Pay attention to both.  The width of a letter will have $\cos$ significance and the height of a letter will have $\sin$ significance.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/0CTb18F.png

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have already completely rewritten the question. It's probably okay now.

Comment: Please actually specify *what* your criteria are. Do the letters most all be allocated the same height that *must* be the same for every letter no matter how tall? And must there be exactly nine letter and the must add to 900. And you say they must always fill up this entire height? Why not the same restriction for width?

Comment: All the letters are the same height. And since (unlike the picture) I use a monospaced font, so does the same width. The size of the shape can be any and 9 is the max number of letters. All words with a lower number of letters will use the same size. "P" should be placed in the center and the position of the other letters with a space 5 will be derived from it. The space between the first and last letter with the edge of the shape must be min 5, but it can also be 50. And since the word can be written at any angle, it mustn’t exceed the max height and width, which is in both cases 83,333...

Comment: I modified and went into much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what conditions are required for you.

Consider this task:  The text will appear so that the lower left hand corner of each letter will be aligned on a line slanted at an angle. The line will go through the  letter and emerge either out of the left or top side and the lower left hand left hand corner of the next (or previous letter will begin five space latter on the line.

So our initial data is the angle of the line, the height and width of the paper, and the text we need to write and the dimensions of all letters and symbols.

First calculation, without scaling to fit the paper how long would the line need to be.

First notice if angle is $0$ to $90$ the line will go from the lower left hand corner of the current letter on a path that has an rightward horizontal change at least that of the width of the current letter and a upward height change of the height of the current letter.   We'll call this method 1.

If the angle is $-90$ to $0$ the line will go from the lower left hand corner of the current letter on a path that has a rightward horizontal change at least that of the width of the current letter and a downward height change of the height of the *next* letter. Call this method 2.

If angle is $90$ to $180$ the line will go from the lower left hand corner of the current letter on a path that has a *leftward* horizontal change at least that of the width of the *next* letter and a *upward* height change of the height of the *next* letter. Call this method 3.

If angle is $-180$ to $-90$ the line will go from the lower left hand corner of the current letter on a path that has a leftward horizontal change at least that of the width of the *next* letter and a downward height change of the height of the *next* letter. Call this method 4.

The "methods" start and $(0,0)$.  Now we will either go horizontally across the width of the appropriate letter (plus five for the buffer) and go vertically that width times the $\tan$ of the angle, or it will go vertically the height of the appropriate letter (plus five for the buffer) and go across that height times the $\cot $ of the angle.  Choose the greater distance and let that be $(x_1, y_1)$.  Whether to appropriate letter is the current or the next one, and whether you go up or down or left and right depend on the method.

Do that to get the coordinates of the base of all the letters.  If you did method 3 or 4 you will need find the point *before* $(0,0)$ (by the same method) to make room for the first letter.  If you did method 1 or 2 you will need to make the point after the lower left corner of the last letter to make room for the last letter.

Now adjust take the highest/lowest points the letters reach and the left and right most point the letters reach.

You will now have the coordinates of a rectangle and the coordinate of the bottom left corner of every letter.  Scale it to fit the page.

==== old answer====

So lets say that you have a letter $X$ with width $w_x$ and and hieght $h_x$ and centered at $(a_x, b_x)$. then you want to place the next letter smack next to it but at an angle of $\theta$.  The first point to clear then horizontal edge would be  $(a_x + h_x, b_x + h*x\sin \theta)$,  The first point to clear the vertical edge is $(a_x + w_x* \cos \theta, b_x + w_x)$.  As you need to clear both edges you would choose  $(a_x + \max(h_x, w_x* \cos \theta), b_x + \max(w_x, h*x\sin \theta)$.

Figure out the center of the second letter similarly.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the question. I'm not saying that your calculation is wrong, but I don't know the height and width of the letters in advance and I have to calculate. More of a question I completely rewrote.

Comment: This method doesn't assume you know that height and lengths of the letters in advanced either.  If you know one you can calculate where the edge of the next letter should be.  Then when you get the next letters dimensions you do the same again.

Comment: The problem is that I only know the coordinates "connecting" the imaginary line (see the picture). From this I can easily calculate the angle and also the center of the middle letter (if the number is odd). I don't know anything more at the beginning.

Comment: Don't try to figure the spaces each letter needs first.  Figure out how big the thing for letters being a standard height and then scale down (or up).